# Why does colon in shell command read the wrong file?

Tags: external-command, ex-mode

I write ruby test files in vim, and regularly run tests from the file I'm editing by running

`:!rspec %:N`

or something similar (to execute the test at line N). The *problem* is that when the first digit of N is an 8, like:

`:!rspec %:89`

I get an error:

`cannot load such file -- /.../foo_spec.rb9`

So it looks like the sequence `%:8` means something inside of a colon command. Additionally, if I *escape* the colon: `rspec %\:89` works fine.

But why is this happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you already know `%` in the vim command line is resolved to the path name of
the file in the current buffer. But `%` can  be modified by adding a modifier.
A modifier starts with a `:` and `:8` is a valid modifier.

See `:help filename-modifiers` for the full list of modifiers. For `:8` it
says:

> ```
>   :8  Converts the path to 8.3 short format (currently only on
>       MS-Windows).  Will act on as much of a path that is an
>       existing path.
> ```

On Linux a `%:8` is just like `%`, so `%:89` results in `%9`.

Comment: Since OP might not know about `%` in general it might help to start with something like "unescaped % resolves to the path of the file in the current buffer" and then ":8 is a modifier of % that...".

Comment: Aha! Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I can confirm I do know about `%` :-)

Comment: Okay, cool. Still might be good to give a little context IMHO by mentioning `%` alone...only mention is currently "the path".

Comment: @BLayer I see, we try to provide answers that are more than a link and a short quote.

Comment: @Ralf Yeah! I try to keep in mind "hypothetical, future, non-OP readers" for which _context is king_ when writing an answer. :) Cheers.